# How can I recover from switching to a non-existent branch in svn?

Tags: svn, branch, recovery

How I got into a pickle:

```
svn switch http://repo/project/rbanches/branchname/plugins/com.securemacprogramming.myplugin com.securemacprogramming.myplugin
```

What this caused (in addition to "incoming delete on switch" in svn status):

```
svn switch http://repo/project/branches/branchname/plugins/com.securemacprogramming.myplugin com.securemacprogramming.myplugin
svn: . is not under version control

svn switch http://repo/project/trunk/plugins/com.securemacprogramming.myplugin com.securemacprogramming.myplugin
svn: . is not under version control

svn revert
[nothing changes]
```

I've managed to get into a semi-usable state by completely deleting the plugin folder, but `svn up` from the parent won't recover the content. I can check it out into the correct location from `svn co`, but then the working copy seems to come from two repositories: the parent level thinks the folder isn't under version control (i.e. it shows '?'), the myplugins folder shows the correct `svn info` etc. So how can I recover to where the folders are connected in subversion's mind and are on the branches I expect, short of deleting the local copy and starting again?

I did at least make no changes on the server during that messing about, though have of course since committed the changes on the branch I was trying to make in the first place.

Comment: Clean checkout into a fresh working copy seems to be safest/easiest. Do you have local changes to merge?

Comment: @Thilo yes, all on the branch.

Comment: Get a fresh working copy, copy the changed files over into it (only the files, no .svn directories). Semi-usable svn working copies are dangerous.

Comment: @Thilo thanks, that's the approach I'm taking now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that had I passed the --depth=infinity option to `svn revert`, I could have backed out the changes it thought would be incoming on `svn switch`.